# Inconsistent accessibility on class

Tags: c#, winforms, access-modifiers

I am getting the following error

> Error Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Project3_MineSweeper.DB'
>   is less accessible than field
>   'Project3_MineSweeper.Form2.db'

Here is the code in DB.cs

```
class DB
{
    private string connectionString;

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return connectionString; }
    }

    private SqlConnection connection;

    public SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get { return connection; }
    }

    public DB()
    {
        connectionString="Data Source=NGFAJAR-PC\\FAJAR;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True";
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

And this is the code of Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public DB db; //it's here where I am getting the error

    private Form3 form3;
    public Form2()
    {
        db = new DB();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ...
}
```

Lastly, Form3.cs

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    private Form2 form2;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void loadData()
    {
        DataTable dt = form2.db.GetData();
        dgvScore.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

What's wrong? And what should I do to fix it?
Thanks for your appreciated attention and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `class DB` as `internal class DB` or `public class DB`.

Comment: Or maybe change the field from `public DB db;` into `internal DB db;`. There's no need to always resolve this by making things _more_ accessible!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Certainly - but given the information provided, the answer is `public`.  More information would possibly suggest a lower accessibility.  In all likelihood, since these are `Form`s he's dealing with, everything that he has `public` could be `internal`.  That seems beyond the scope of this question though.

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong?

The type `DB` is declared as `class DB` with no explicit access modifier. This is probably good. Then the default accessibility for a direct member of a namespace (`Project3_MineSweeper`), is `internal`. So `DB` is an `internal` class.

Now `Form2` is a `public` class. Public means that anyone, even code outside this "program" (this assembly) can see `Form2`. Now `Form2` has a field `db` which is also `public`. So `db` is public inside a public class, so `db` can be seen from the outside. But here's the problem: People outside your program don't even know there's a type called `Project3_MineSweeper.DB`. So how can they see a field of a "secret" type? Here's the inconsistency.

> And what should I do to fix it?

Make the accessibilities compatible, for example be changing the field to `internal`, so:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    internal DB db;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you DB class like so

```
public class DB
{
    ....
}
```